# How to end an endless stream of alert messages in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, alert

How can I close endless alert in PhantomJS?

a website has endless alert

I used

```
page.onAlert = function(msg) {
  console.log('ALERT: ' + msg);
};
```

to check whether the website has alert

but this method you will never stop because that's an endless alert

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Is the page only calling `alert()` *once*, but PhantomJS prints this alert message infinitely? Please [edit] your question to describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to print all alerts that the page you're visiting sends your way. Simply remove the handler to silence them:

```
page.onAlert = function(msg) {
    console.log('ALERT: ' + msg);
    page.onAlert = function(){};
};
```

This prints only the first alert. You can make this more sophisticated by adding counting alerts or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for every reloaded page that would have an alert later.

```
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

See more reference [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20).